# Is it possible to use a fully open source workflow for print design?

Tags: print-design, workflow, cmyk, open-source

Is it possible to use only open-source tools in order to produce professional level artwork? Has anyone actually done it? If not, where are the current gaps?

Assume I'm producing a small multi-page brochure including photos, line art and CMYK + a spot colour, and need to take it as far as a PDF I can hand off to the printers.

**I've now added a bounty in order to encourage additional answers.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A bit of overlap with my answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-free-open-source-image-design-programs-can-you-recommend/187#187), and you can grab urls from there, but yep, a Gimp/Inkscape/Scribus workflow might be ok.

Actually done it? Yep. I indeed work with mostly free and open source tools with no complaints.

In my experience, you often have to heavily use your brain and create your tricks to achieve certain industry demanded requirements when the open source tool hasn't yet received some feature. For this reason, the time factor is key to decide. If what's needed is a very fast, stressful environment, no hassle workflow, very demanding on features, (often is the typical graphic artist job) imho only the best of the best commercial tools would keep it totally safe. Still so, I prefer open source workflows.

Comment: Good stuff. Where you talk about working around missing features - any examples?

Comment: Eu. Would be very long to answer (not saying your question is vague..) because I was referring like he did, to most open source tools for this matter. Well, if want some examples, just the fact that Inkscape does not have yet a propper support of CMYK, neither (at least in Windows) a full support in Gimp, that makes it quite an obstacle for many situations. Still, you can do stuff (oh, btw, forgot the important sk1, terrible memory, just updated the other thread) with tricks and all.

Comment: I guess another one is that spot colours are normally specified as Pantone references, which are copyright and so aren't going to be available as libraries in any open-source software.

Comment: I, too, have been playing with the Scribus+Inkscape+Gimp workflow. It's certainly doable. You may have to pass on prepress issues like trapping to the printer-side via PDF workflow. CMYK shouldn't be a huge hurdle. That's something the prepress RIP should be able to handle. Spot color omission would be a bit tougher to handle prepress side, though.

Comment: How does the economics of FOSS vs. commercial work out to save money, then? The costs of Adobe and Quark are legendary in the industry, but it's not as though we have to pay them every time we output a job. If the FOSS tools don't support technologies as core to printing as CMYK and Pantone, then I would argue that the support costs associated with FOSS tools are just as much as the commercial licenses.

Comment: @philip...that's certainly true. From a pure cost perspective, it's an issue of scale. If a person does 20 hours of freelance a year, it's probably not profitable to dump a few grand into the Adobe suite. But otherwise, yea, it's likely cheaper to go with the mature 'standard' platform of Adobe. Lots of people, though, are looking more at FOSS from a purely political POV.

Comment: Actually...this could be a great niche for a quality printer...focus on handling work produced via an OS workflow.

Comment: I get the whole FOSS debate, but when we're trying to run a business, it really becomes a question of how much our time is worth. A lot of the more successful FOSS projects I have seen and used have found a way to monetize their work one way or another, typically through support contracts to help users get up to speed. It seems to me that Scribus needs to fill in some rather large gaps in functionality before it can really contend with its commercial competition before it will have any impact on the market. Personally, I think the market needs a good kick in the pants, so I'm all for it.

Comment: From a film or plate perspective spot/CMYK issues weaken. Before all these great color features designers realized that to the ink every plate is color agnostic. We routinely designed in B&W then relabeled film. We exported Photoshop spot color layers, flattened them, and printed them as grayscale and then instructed the printer which Pantone color to use for that plate. Often we manually added color names between crop marks. I’ve never found spot color to be much of an issue no matter the tools.

Comment: CMYK from RGB files could be tricky in the olden days, but for years we had to trust that the service bureau would get it right. As cheap as proofs are now, even today just letting them convert the color space it how many professionals work.