# Need program to design a printable poster

Tags: resolution

I'm trying to design a printable poster about wine infographics. I need a program that I can design this poster for print, about 18X24 inches size. Basically, I need to be able to add text and pictures (glasses and icons you see in the picture) and some basic paint tools.

I tried some online programs like befunky, which for some reason didn't give me the resolution I wanted. I'm new to all this.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What free/open source image design programs can you recommend?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-free-open-source-image-design-programs-can-you-recommend)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Illustrator for design of print material.

Its a professional design program so not exactly easy at first. It is extremely flexible and capable of outputting all major file types at any resolution.

If you already have this poster designed you can open it in Illustrator, vectorize it if need be, and output any size.

If you need to design it in Illustrator you'll need to find that font file.

Illustrator is available from Adobe for a 30-day free trial.